# Normalization: Converting from 3NF to BCNF,4NF & 5NF

Tags: database-design, database-schema

How can I convert 3NF process upto 5NF for following schema ?

```
Member (memcode,name,title,address,sex,dob,occupation).
Occupation_Category (occupation,category).
Region (address,region).
Member_Response (memcode,subject,num-sent,num-replied).
Offer_Details (offercode,title,subject).
Offer (offercode,date,price,num-sold ).
Offer_Target (offercode,date,target-category,age-group,target-region).
Supplier (suppcode,name,address,phoneno).
Item (itemcode,description).
Item_in_Offer (offercode,itemcode,qty).
Item_Supplier (offercode,itemcode,suppcode).
```

Comment: What changes do *you* propose to make this conversion, and why? Note that the forms (in sequence, 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, 5NF) are all more restrictive than the previous form. Wikipedia explains them all pretty well if you're unsure what the specific requirements for each form are.

Answer (score 0):

```
Member (memcode,name,title,address,sex,dob,occupation).
Occupation_Category (occupation,category).
Region (address,region).
Member_Response (memcode,subject,num-sent,num-replied).
Offer_Details (offercode,title,subject).
Offer (offercode,date,price,num-sold ).
Offer_Target (offercode,date,target-category,age-group,target-region).
Supplier (suppcode,name,address,phoneno).
Item (itemcode,description).
Item_in_Offer (offercode,itemcode,qty).
Item_Supplier (offercode,itemcode,suppcode).
```